# What form should the music learning question below take so as to get past moderators?

Tags: discussion

I've been trying for almost two days to get the following straightforward music learning question past moderators. Either the justification for refusal given has been contradictory, or the requirements -on being complied with- replaced by others. Can anyone suggest what form it should take to get accepted?

> [What in your experience are the main impediments to learning online
>   using video chat?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17068/what-in-your-experience-are-the-main-impediments-to-learning-online-using-video)

Comment: There's also three moderators in total, what you are having problems with is actually the user community on the site. A tip is to read up on what the QA sites are for. But do what @Shevliaskovic recommends and put a question on the Meta and maybe things will become clearer.

Comment: As I said when you first asked the question, I think you potentially have a good subject for your question, but I think it needs to be asked in a way that is not negative from the outset. Although, it is also worth pointing out that a question of this type may not attract a definitive answer, but instead a number of opinions.

Comment: Sorry to be meta-meta(!) How are questions migrated? Is this a moderator only facility?

Comment: Recommended reading. http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/161/community-wiki-list-recommendation-questions-and-you

Comment: @DrMayhem, I thought that closing it for migration was for all of us. At the post on the main site, I see `migrated to meta.music.stackexchange.com by Shevliaskovic, Meaningful Username, Fergus, American Luke, Dom 43 mins ago `. Or did some mod migrate it after we flagged it?

Comment: 5 votes to migrate to meta automatically moves it

Answer (score 7):

The guidelines should be fairly clear - we do have some discussion underway on scope and where the boundaries are, but while people have been trying to help you, the question is still not suitable here.

As I pointed out, it doesn't appear to be about music. If you asked exactly the same question about learning origami, would that make this question about origami?

Answer (score 6):

Well, in the first case, as someone else has said, you are asking people why it doesn't work, rather than how to do it.  In the second case, your question is very broad.  You don't mention music at all, and you don't mention what aspect of music you are wanting to learn.  Some things work better than others.  So, narrow the focus of your question and be more specific.  For example:

> Do you feel that learning to play the tuba using video chat can be
>   effective?

Edit: Ok, now I've seen the original that spawned this meta-question.  Yes, you do talk about music.  You also come across as a particularly unpopular schoolteacher, first pontificating on your own ideas, then didactically telling everyone what rules we must follow if we are to be permitted to involve ourselves in answering your question.  Your sarcastic comments to the moderators are based on the idea that the only reason that they are blocking your question is that they are too obtuse to understand it without your "clarifications".

So, I revise my answer thus: start with an attitude adjustment.  Once you have adjusted your attitude sufficiently to not care whether or not anyone who is giving advice and suggestions is "really" attacking you, try looking at the suggestions given.  Then, try asking the question over again.

Comment: I think your example question will be opinion based. Maybe you can transform it into something like `Is it possible to learn to play the tuba using video chat?`

Comment: I think that would be opinion based too. :)

Comment: Purely subjective questions are not acceptable, particularly opinion polls.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that this type of question is *relevant* as a "music pedagogy" question: in what ways are current teleconference technologies, suitable/unsuitable for learning voice.

However there are issues in terms of

- The question as currently written is too loosely constrained, there are dozens of facets to dealing with teleconference from latency and sound quality up through the more intuitive/emotional aspects that arise from not being literally present with the other participant
- The original question was even less constrained since it included technologies (inter-browser communications) over and above just telepresence.
- questions that include strong statements of opinion tend to imply that the answers will be similarly opinion based (In an ideal world this wouldn't be the case, but we don't live in an ideal world)
- Just listing the impediments  is not a particularly useful question (which on a strict reading is what you asked for), gearing more towards techniques and practices to enhance the upside, and mitigate the downsides might help.
- Context of the specific situation that you are in where the answers to this question would help you would also make the question more concrete and answerable (without this context the question  comes across a bit like "lets have a discussion")
- Answers to the original question could become obsolete as technology changes

So, I'd

1. Remove/re-work the introductory bit
2. Focus in on one or more of the facets of the situation, which will
3. Limit the scope of answers
4. to things that lead to (or could lead to) productive solutions to the problem(s).

Answer (score 3):

A good thing to do in my experience, when entering a new forum, is to not only read the guidelines, but take some time to get acquainted with the forum. Get a feeling for what the usual form of communication is, how strictly the guidelines are actually adhered to etc.

This is one of the least hostile forums (using forum in the wide sense) I've seen on the internets, people are in general very helpful. So relax and try some constructive dialog instead of turning defensive. It is not about harassing, it's merely that your question is not in the scope of the site, in the forms you have presented it.

Comment: That's not true that we are a forum. We are different as many of the questions that do not fit here (for example opinion based questions and discussion based questions) would be accepted in a forum. We are a question and answer site with a community.

Comment: @Dom: So even the widest sense of forum excludes this site? It's a mouthful to write "...the least hostile question and answer site with a community..." and it loses the comparison with other places on the internet. Was what I meant completely lost? Please suggest edits if so.

Comment: @Dom "Online community"? So everyone is happy